# Angular 1 fix Ng-Model disable value

Tags: angularjs

When putting `ng-model` the value of the input dispairs 
ex

```
<input type="text"  name="" ng-model='myInput' value="gooo">
```

The goo doesn't appear, even if I use ng-value instead of value

```
<input type="text"  name="" ng-model='myInput' ng-value="gooo">
```

It doesn't appear as well if i removed `ng-model` it appears

Can I use it this way without using data binding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you said `ng-value="gooo"`, angular tries to find `gooo` variable inside scope. If you directly want to set `ng-model` value using `ng-value`, you should have been wrap in `'`(single quote).

```
<input type="text"  name="" ng-model='myInput' ng-value="'gooo'">
```

You can also set the value of `gooo` inside respective controller, like `$scope.myInput = 'gooo'`

Answer (score 1):

You should use the model in order to bind the value instead of ng-value.

$scope.myInput = "goo".
Then in html code just put ng-model, it will bind the correct value for you.